# Understanding "Expression does not compute the number of elements in this array"

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, warnings, clang++

Using Apple Clang 12.0.0 to compile this code:

```
int my_array[10];
int arr_size = sizeof(my_array) / sizeof(decltype(my_array[0]));
```

And getting this warning/error:

`Expression does not compute the number of elements in this array; element type is 'int', not 'decltype(my_array[0])' (aka 'int &')`

Note, this is simplified code. In the real code instead of 'int' there's a class type, instead of '10' there's an expression.

Why am I getting this warning, and what is the correct way to calculate the array size without warnings?

Comment: The warning looks wrong to me: `decltype(my_array[0])` should in fact be `int` and not `int&`. The workaround is simple though - just drop `decltype`, make it `sizeof(my_array[0])`. Or use `std::extent<decltype(my_array)>::value`

Comment: This leaves the question why the warning?

Comment: Please add the c++ tag to questions about C++ so that more users will see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a partial answer.

First of all it is not surprising that `decltype(my_array[0])` is of type int& and not int. Just remember that you can assign to it and change the value at `my_array[0]`.

Secondly, your code should be correct anyway because for `sizeof`

> When applied to a reference type, the result is the size of the referenced type.
> --[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof).

Now for why clang reports a warning I am not sure. It might just be that it recognizes T and T& as entirely different types passed to the two `sizeof` operators and that they have some sort of exception for the common `sizeof(my_array)/sizeof(my_array[0])` pattern.

Have you tried std::remove_reference_t in front of your decltype to remove the warning? Or just dropping the decltype as suggested in the comments?

**Update**
For some C++ stylepoints you could also drop the sizeof pattern entirely and use a metaprogramming technique

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
constexpr size_t size_of_array( T (&_arr)[N]) {
   return N;
}
```

You can use that as `size_of_array(my_array)`.

Comment: I removed `decltype`.